# sqlite nullpointer exception

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String sel="SELECT "+stdb.sid+"," +stdb.amt+", "+stdb.details+" FROM "+stdb.tname;
        Cursor c=dobj.rawQuery(sel, null);
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            int id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(stdb.sid));
            int amt=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(stdb.amt));
            String printdetail=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(stdb.details));
            TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Log.e("gg",""+amt ); //the value of amt comes in logcat
        tv1.setText(""+amt);//this gives nullpointer exception
```

here i am trying to get a value from an edittext i am able to see the value in the logcat but when i try to print the same with a settext(TextView) i get a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Comment: If amt is not null, then tv1 must be null.

Comment: @JesusFreke sir i am getting the value i entered in the edittext in the logcat

Comment: Right, so when you try to dereference `tv1`, you get the `NullPointerException`.  The value of `amt` isn't the problem.

Comment: @Argyle thanks sir the porblem was with the textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(tv1!=NULL)
    tv1.setText(""+amt);
else
    Log.e("WHOA, this is NULL!!!");
```

And see if it prints the else log. If it does, that means your tv1 view is not getting initialized  correctly. If not, will see what we can do.